# Why ajax loadXml callback does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't see where I did a mistake : my table is empty, I'd like to use console to debug but don't know how to.

Update : this sample works http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2 I used code from there but with different xml I don't understand why mine not working

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>XML Data Block Demo</title>

    <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    function parseXML(input) {
    var xml = input.responseXML;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
    var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagName("Stock");

    var table="<tr><th>Ticker</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
    for (i = 0; i <lineItems.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("Ticker")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("Price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";
    }  

    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
    }

    function loadXML() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        parseXML(xhttp);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/ajax/xml/demo1/stocks.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadXML()";>
    <table id="table"></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is `input` within `parseXML` ? Tried substituting `.responseText` for `.responseXML` ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Why would `input` be accessible through the console? It's local to the function. Have you tried checking from the network tab what the server's actual response is? Or even `console.log(xml)`?

Comment: @guest271314 this sample works http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2 I used code from there but with different xml I don't understand why mine not working

Comment: @Juhana sorry I'm beginner, I'm still learning how to use javascript console using your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your function with the content of [stocks.xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms762660(v=vs.85).aspx) and it works fine excepts on ie11, so i suggest you the following change:

```js
function parseXML(input) {
  var xml = input.responseXML || input.responseText;
  var doc;
  try {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
  } catch(err) {
    doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    doc.async = false;
    doc.loadXML(xml);
  }
```

The full code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XML Data Block Demo</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function parseXML(input) {
            var xml = input.responseXML || input.responseText;
            var doc;
            try {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
            } catch(err) {
                doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                doc.async = false;
                doc.loadXML(xml);
            }
            var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagName("Stock");

            var table="<tr><th>Ticker</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
            for (i = 0; i <lineItems.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                        lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("Ticker")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                        "</td><td>" +
                        lineItems[i].getElementsByTagName("Price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                        "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
        }

        function loadXML() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    parseXML(xhttp);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/ajax/xml/demo1/stocks.xml", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadXML()";>
<table id="table"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the xml content is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<portfolio xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <stock exchange="nasdaq">
        <name>new</name>
        <symbol>zzzz</symbol>
        <price dt:dt="number">20.313</price>
    </stock>
    <stock exchange="nyse">
        <name>zacx corp</name>
        <symbol>ZCXM</symbol>
        <price dt:dt="number">28.875</price>
    </stock>
    <stock exchange="nasdaq">
        <name>zaffymat inc</name>
        <symbol>ZFFX</symbol>
        <price dt:dt="number">92.250</price>
    </stock>
    <stock exchange="nasdaq">
        <name>zysmergy inc</name>
        <symbol>ZYSZ</symbol>
        <price dt:dt="number">20.313</price>
    </stock>
</portfolio>
```

The result on my computer with Chrome / IE / FireFox last verions is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this sample works http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2 I used code from there but with different xml I don't understand why mine not working, so what I need is specific help on my example not another one thanks.